# For which values of $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ does $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n^\alpha \left (\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}} \right )$ converge

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I have a question in my analysis course that I have been trying for a long time and I'm not quite sure how to answer it. I have an idea for an answer but I'm not sure if it's right.

Also note the only theorems we have learned for determining the convergence of series so far is the comparison test and the theorem that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k^\alpha}$ is convergent iff $\alpha > 1$ for $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$.

**Question**

For what values of $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ does the following series converge?

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n^\alpha \left (\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}} \right )$$

**My solution (so far)**

First

\begin{align}
n^\alpha \left (\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}} \right ) &= n^\alpha \left (\frac{\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n} \cdot \sqrt{n+1}} \right ) \\ &= n^{\alpha-\frac{1}{2}} \left (\frac{(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n})(\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n})}{\sqrt{n+1} \cdot(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n})} \right ) \\ &= n^{\alpha-\frac{1}{2}} \left (\frac{1}{n+1+\sqrt{n^2+n}} \right ) \\ &= \frac{1}{n^{\frac{3}{2}-\alpha}} \left (\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{n}+\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n}}} \right )
\end{align}
Now my idea was that you notice the term in the brackets is bounded for $n \in \mathbb{N}$
$$\frac{1}{4} \leq \left (\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{n}+\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n}}} \right ) \leq \frac{1}{2}$$
And so as a result, the convergence of the series of a whole depends on the term
$$\frac{1}{n^{\frac{3}{2}-\alpha}}$$
and so I can apply the second theorem I know to put a bound on $\alpha$ for convergence. But this does not seem like an acceptable argument, because it is such a loose statement and not based on any actual results we have learned.

Alternatively I thought about the significance of the $1+\frac{1}{n}$ since it appears twice, but I didn't really get anywhere with that.

So is my answer at all going in the right direction or not? And if it is how can I continue? Otherwise what alternative approach is there?

Comment: You are in the right direction.

Comment: What makes you doubt your first approach? If you can prove these inequalities then you prove by the comparison test that the original series converges if and only if $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^{\frac{3}{2}-\alpha}}$ does. If you could use the limit comparison test, the exercise would have been a bit easier, but you did a good job without it.

Comment: An alternative analysis of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}}$ is: $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}}\left(\sqrt{1+\frac1n}-1\right)$$ and using the well-known $(1+x)^\alpha\sim \alpha x (x\to0)$ to obtain  $\sqrt{1+\frac1n}-1\sim \frac1n$ and then $$n^\alpha \left (\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}} \right )\sim n^{\alpha-3/2},\qquad n\to\infty.$$

Comment: @Mark Yeah I'm not quite sure why it didn't click, but that does make sense now. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your argument is completely fine, indeed for $\frac 3 2-\alpha>1 $ that is $\alpha <\frac12$

$$ \frac{1}{n^{\frac{3}{2}-\alpha}} \left (\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{n}+\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n}}} \right )\le  \frac{1}{n^{\frac{3}{2}-\alpha}}$$

which series converges otherwise

$$ \frac{1}{n^{\frac{3}{2}-\alpha}} \left (\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{n}+\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n}}} \right )\ge  \frac{1}{n^{\frac{3}{2}-\alpha}} \cdot \frac1{10}$$

which series diverges.

Answer (score 3):

*Just for your curiosity.*

As said in comments and answer, you did a good job and, for sure, you are on the right track.

You could go futher using the fact that
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}}=\frac 1{2 n^{\frac 32}}\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k\,\frac {a_k}{n^k}$$ where the first $a_k$ are
$$\left\{1,\frac{3}{4},\frac{5}{8},\frac{35}{64},\frac{63}{128},\frac{231}{512},\frac{429}{1024},\cdots\right\}$$

$$S_k=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac {n^\alpha}{2 n^{\frac 32}}=\frac{1}{2} \zeta \left(k-\alpha +\frac{3}{2}\right)$$

Answer (score 2):

There is a result stating that

##### *"If $ b_n>0, $and $\frac{a_n}{b_n}\to l >0, l < \infty$.  Then either  $\sum(a_n)$ and $\sum(b_n)$ both converge or both diverge "*

Let $a_n= \frac{1}{n^{\frac{3}{2}-\alpha}} \left (\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{n}+\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n}}} \right )$ and $b_n=\frac{1}{n^{\frac{3}{2}-\alpha}}$

Now $\frac{a_n}{b_n} \to \frac{1}{2}$

and hence $\sum  \frac{1}{n^{\frac{3}{2}-\alpha}} \left (\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{n}+\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n}}} \right )$ converge iff $\frac{1}{n^{3/2-\alpha}}$ converges,

We know that $\sum \frac{1}{n^p}$ converge iff $p>1$

and hence $\sum \frac{1}{n^{3/2-\alpha}}$ converge iff $\frac{3}{2}-\alpha >1$

which implies $\alpha < \frac{1}{2}$

I think this result is called as "Limit comparision test" It can proved easily using comparision test... Try proving it :)